# Cost diff between manual docker on ec2 and ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have two ways of running docker on AWS

1. Ec2 instance and manually installer docker there
2. use ECS

I tried using ECS and saw that it also defined many other services like vps, gateway subnet , cluster etc.

My Questions is what extra cost will be there i run on ECS beside.

LIke if i choose same ec2 instance with ECS as compare to manually installing docker. How much will be the cost difference.

AWS says that there is no diff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference in price. From the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/pricing/)

*There is no additional charge for Amazon EC2 Container Service. You pay for AWS resources (e.g. EC2 instances or EBS volumes) you create to store and run your application. You only pay for what you use, as you use it; there are no minimum fees and no upfront commitments.*

Comment: Does creating cluster , gateway , router, subnet etc incur any charges. Becaus ei won't need those with option 1

Comment: What do you mean by cluster? That's not an AWS concept I'm familiar with. You want an instance, you pay for an instance.  You want two, you pay for two. None of the others are charged, they're all part of VPC which is a free foundation service in AWS.

Comment: I am talking about this  http://postimg.org/image/drpnzok3b/

Comment: You answered your own question when you posted - "AWS says there is no dif". AWS charges for instances, not the glue around them.

Comment: ok thanks , i was worried that i may not get unnecessary charges. So usuaaly whatever the charges may be , i should be able to see after few hours to see what i am chnaged for. Is there any thing which i am only able to see at end of month for surprise?

Comment: You may get charges you don't expect, but not those ones. Additional storage through EBS snapshots, unmapped elastic IPs, traffic to CDN, inter-AZ traffic, etc. You need to learn about AWS costs at a high level, not just ask specific questions.